# Perl or Python: Count total number of different Mac addresses in a file

Tags: python, perl, unique

I have a large file (~10-100MB) that contains thousands of mac addresses and each mac address could appear more than one time in the file.
I want to write a Perl script (or Python script) that returns the total of unique mac addresses. For example, if my file contains

```
"hostmac":"112233445566"
log here
"hostmac":"23AA23AA23AA"
log here
"hostmac":"23AA23AA23AA"
log here
"hostmac":"112233445566"
log here
"hostmac":"77AABB8899CC"
log here
"hostmac":"112233445566"
log here
"hostmac":"112233445566"
log here
"hostmac":"EEFF00112233"
log here
```

I want my Perl/Python script to return 4 because I have 4 unique mac addresses.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Is the format identifcal on every line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the format is precisely as you describe:

```
$ egrep hostmac filename.txt | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, very frateful for your help. That's exactly what I need. Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -nE '$s{$1} = 1 if /hostmac":"(.+?)"/ END{ say scalar keys %s }' file
```

for perl 5.8 and older:

```
perl -ne '$s{$1} = 1 if /hostmac":"(.+?)"/ END{ print scalar keys %s }' file
```

Comment: Perl is so sexy and dirty at the same time.

Comment: @admdrew sexy yes, dirty only if obfuscated :)

Comment: Sometimes perl feels obfuscated even with good code :D

Comment: Thank you so much. I get this error, could you help me out please:

$ perl -nE '$s{$1} = 1 if /hostmac":"(.+?)"/ END{ say scalar keys %s }' test.txt
Unrecognized switch: -E  (-h will show valid options).

$ perl -n '$s{$1} = 1 if /hostmac":"(.+?)"/ END{ say scalar keys %s }' test.txt
Can't open perl script "$s{$1} = 1 if /hostmac":"(.+?)"/ END{ say scalar keys %s }": No such file or directory

Comment: @user2996850 check update; you are using outdated perl version

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every line has the format listed above, the Python would be:

```
len(set([line.split(':')[1] for line in open(path)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A Python solution:

```
with open ('data.txt') as f:
    print len(set(line for line in f if line.startswith('"hostmac":')))
```

This can be a one-liner actually, `print` can be on the same line as `with ...` :-) It's easy to see that a solution which uses `grep`, `uniq` and `wc` is the shortest, though. It's good to learn the Unix tools to do such things in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Python answer using readable Python

```
def count_unique(filename):
    mac_addr = set()
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'hostmac' in line:
                mac_addr.add(line.split('"')[-2])
    return len(mac_addr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print count_unique(sys.argv[1])
```

Python answer using more concise format

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    print len(set(line.split('"')[-2] for line in f if 'hostmac' in line))
```